# how to make interpolated data as a function?

Tags: interpolation

For example,

data1 =

0   1
1   2
3   3
5   2
6   2
9   4
11  5
13  6
14  7
16  8

data2 =

0   2
1   3
2   2
3   1
4   2
6   3
8   4
9   6
11  4
16  7

each data have different x-axis interval. so I cannot calculate about these two data set such as multiply each other or dividing each other.

I have to do interpolation and make the data as a function.

how to make it possible?

ex: data1/data2 or data1 x data2

Comment: Please try to write your code in Mathematica syntax

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

This question is not clear but making a few assumptions this is a direct application of the Interpolation function.

```
data1 = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 6, 2, 9, 4, 11, 5, 13, 6, 14, 7, 16, 8};
data2 = {0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 9, 6, 11, 4, 16, 7};
```

Now assuming that the data is actually x1,y1,x2,y2,...

```
xy1 = Partition[data1,2];
xy2 = Partition[data2,2];
```

Plot it.

```
ListPlot[{xy1,xy2}]

func1 = Interpolation[xy1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
func2 = Interpolation[xy2, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

func1[5]/func2[5]

Show[ListPlot[{xy1, xy2}, PlotRange -> All], Plot[{func1[x], func2[x]}, {x, 0, 15}]]
```

[image: Plot of data and linear interpolation.]